# Cannot use DRAGGABLE, RESIZEABLE & SELECTABLE at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying use Jquery-ui for the first time, and am trying to create a div with all the 3 features mentioned above in the title.

You can find the JSBin link here: https://jsbin.com/haleyucipu/1/edit?html,output

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Visual feedback</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  .ui-resizable-ghost { border: 1px dotted gray; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      ghost: true,
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
      animate: true
    }).draggable().selectable();
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Only, resizeable and draggable work! Selectable doesnt!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried initializing them in a different order?

Comment: Yes! Doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Selectable needs a container, if you look at the [examples](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/), they use `<ol>`.

Consider the following code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Visual feedback</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
    #resizable {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }
    
    #resizable h3 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .ui-selecting {
      background: #FECA40;
      opacity: .65;
    }
    
    .ui-selected {
      background: #F39814;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .ui-resizable-ghost {
      border: 1px dotted gray;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable({
        ghost: true,
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
        animate: true
      }).draggable().parent().selectable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This makes `<body>` the container and now all UI Interactions work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @GaganGanapathySudhirAjjikut this was due to your styling. Updated answer and you can see it is working.

Comment: How do you select it, by just clicking on it right ? I cant see any color on clicking the div

Comment: @GaganGanapathySudhirAjjikut no the click to select is not bubbling up since Drag is grabbing the click event. But you can lasso id by click-n-drag around the element.