# How combine resizable and draggable with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

From [Cannot use DRAGGABLE, RESIZEABLE & SELECTABLE at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56906967/) it can be seen, that resizeability and draggability can be combined for a DIV in a jQuery environment.

However, I have the question of how to create a resizeable and draggable DIV with Vanilla JS.

It's easy, if the div has a structure e.g. with a header, then only the header can be user as handle for dragging and the resize handle in the lower right corner is free to user for resizing. For the user it's easy to understand, that he has to click on the header, if he wants to drag the whole box.

If the div has only one content, the whole box has to be used as handle for dragging with the side effect, that a click on the resize handle is interpreted as drag event and no resizing is possible.

Small test program for these 2 cases:
https://jsfiddle.net/RanneR/skLvtehc/7/

```
<h2>Test resizeable and moveable</h2>
<h4>Block1 without header</h4>
<div class="area">
    <div class="block freemover">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h4>Block2 with header</h4>
<div class="area">
    <div class="block freemover">
        <h4 class="anchor">Move me</h4>
        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a movable class for my own project. although you have to modify it according to your needs, but should help get you started.

```js
class lexMovable {

    constructor(element, node = [ document ] ) {
        this.node = node
        this.el = element

        if ( this.el ) {
            this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this)
            this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this)
            this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this)
        }
    }

    setHandle( handle ) {
        this.handle = handle
        return this
    }

    setCallback( callback ) {
        this.callback = callback
        return this
    }
    
    mouseDown( event ) {
        if ( this.callback?.start ) this.callback.start( event, this.el )
        else this.el.classList.add('lex-moving')        
        for ( const node of this.node ) {
            node.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp)
            node.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove)
            node.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp)
        }
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp)
    }
    
    mouseUp( event ) {
        if ( this.callback?.end ) this.callback.end( event, this.el )
        else this.el.classList.remove('lex-moving')
        for ( const node of this.node ) {
            node.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp)
            node.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove)
            node.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp)
        }
        this.el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp)
    }
    
    mouseMove(event) {
        if ( this.callback?.move ) {
            this.callback.move( event, this.el )
        } else {
                const style = window.getComputedStyle(this.el)
            const x = (parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('left')) || 0) + event.movementX
            const y = (parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('top')) || 0) + event.movementY
            const rect = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()
            const viewHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight
            const viewWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
            const maxX = viewWidth - rect.width
            const maxY = viewHeight - rect.height
            const constrainedX = Math.max(0, Math.min(x, maxX))
            const constrainedY = Math.max(0, Math.min(y, maxY))
            this.el.style.position = 'absolute'
            this.el.style.top = constrainedY + 'px'
            this.el.style.left = constrainedX + 'px'
        }
    }
    
    run() {
        const handle = this.handle ?? this.el
        handle.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown)
    }

    stop() {
        const handle = this.handle ?? this.el
        handle.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown)
    }
}

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

const movable1 = new lexMovable(boxes[0])
movable1.run()
const movable2 = new lexMovable(boxes[1])
const handle = document.querySelector('.heading')
movable2.setHandle(handle).run()
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  resize: both;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgb(75 85 99);
  border: 2px solid #222;
  overflow: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, red 10px, transparent 10px);
}
.second {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px
}
.heading {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.lex-moving {
  background: orange;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  I am box
</div>
<div class="box second">
  <div class="heading">Move me</div>
  I am box
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @silver, thank you very much - that works!

If the mouse is moved slowly the box is dragged. With fast mouse movement the mouse looses dragging functionality and resizing is done.

??? but honestly, if I read the code I do not understand, where are the main differences compared to my snippet that led to the different behavior.

Comment: OK, I got it. I missed a this.elmnt.onmouseleave in my dragMouseDown method. Now it works. THANK YOU again.

Comment: @RanneR to improve resizable implementation, just append a small div (maybe 20x20) at the bottom right corner of the div where that resize is located during movable initialization, then on mouseDown event, just return directly if the event.target is that div to prevent starting the movable

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example provided by @silver I updated and cleaned my test program. It now works fine. Thanks again.

https://jsfiddle.net/RanneR/skLvtehc/12/

```
class freeMover {
constructor(elmnt, options) {
    console.log('freeMover - elmnt, options', elmnt, options);
    this.elmnt = elmnt;
    this.anchor = elmnt;
    this.pos = {};
    if ( this.elmnt ) {
        this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this)
        this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this)
        this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this)
    }
    if (options.anchor) {
        const anchor = elmnt.querySelector(options.anchor);
        if (anchor) {this.anchor = anchor;}
        console.log('freeMover - anchor', anchor);
    }
    this.anchor.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this));
}
mouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log('mouseDown - event', e);
    this.pos.baseX = this.elmnt.offsetLeft - e.clientX;
    this.pos.baseY = this.elmnt.offsetTop - e.clientY;
    this.elmnt.classList.add('dragging');
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
    this.elmnt.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
}
mouseMove(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    this.elmnt.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.elmnt.style.left = (this.pos.baseX + e.clientX) + "px";
    this.elmnt.style.top = (this.pos.baseY + e.clientY) + "px";
}
mouseUp() {
    this.elmnt.classList.remove('dragging');
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
    this.elmnt.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseUp);
}
```

}